# Mac OS X Server Mail services and Push Notifications to iOS devices

Tags: macos, email, server.app, apns

- I'm running OS X 10.9 with Server 3.0.1 on a Mac residing on a private subnet sitting behind a router whose WAN port is plugged into a cable modem, hence the ISP is a well known cable internet service provider.
- This server has its DNS correctly configured (i.e., the result of "sudo changeip -checkhostname" on the server via command line yields perfect results).
- This server is running an Open Directory Master.
- Dynamic DNS is correctly configured for the router, and resolves the public IP address assigned by my ISP to the same domain name as the server (I forward any required ports for services I run).
- This server also has installed a server certificate signed by a trusted CA (i.e., Go Daddy) and is working perfectly for all OS X Server services including Open Directory.
- This server also has the Mail service configured (SMTP and IMAP) with no problems (I can send and receive mail to/from the server.
- This server server also has push notifications enabled and has a push notification certificate installed perfectly (obtained from Apple's push notification certificate portal, just renewed a few days ago).
- I have some iOS devices running iOS 7.0.4. I have configured Mail on these iOS devices to send and receive mail to/from the aforementioned server for a few different user accounts on the server. This works fine (tested, can send and receive mail no problems).
- The aforementioned iOS devices mail settings for the aforementioned server have been configured to receive push notifications when mail is received to said user accounts on the server.

With all of that said, the iOS devices are **sometimes** able to receive push notifications from the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) (APNS "cloud") in situations when the iOS devices reside on the same private subnet as the Mac server (via Wi-Fi), and when they reside on the public Internet (via cellular data networks or public Wi-Fi networks such as coffee shops).

Thus, push notifications **do** work when mail messages on the server are received, but not always. After a period of time has elapsed on the server whereby no email messages have been received (seems to be several hours but I haven't yet been able to pinpoint it precisely), the server apparently loses what is supposed to be a **persistent** connection with the APNS gateway. OS X Server unfortunately does not log when this connection is lost. Then, when a new email message finally arrives again after several hours and is received by the server, the iOS devices do **not** receive their expected push notifications and instead OS X Server consistently logs an error message like this one (the only differences being of course the process ID and time/date stamp):

```
11/26/13 5:48:11.762 AM push_notify[181]: stream: received error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer on: incoming stream: APN to host: gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

Once the above error type is recorded in the logs, a subsequent email message sent to the server successfully generates a push notification message on the configured iOS devices so long as the subsequent message is sent before minimal time has elapsed (i.e., several hours). I do not port forward ports 2195 or 2196 from the router to the Mac server because Apple's [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4264) implies these ports are for outgoing traffic (from the server to the APNS gateway) unless I've misunderstood.

An excerpt in Apple's Mac Developer Library Technical Note TN2265 caught my attention with respect to **idle**:

> An occasional disconnect while your provider is idle is nothing to be
>   concerned about; just re-establish the connection and carry on. If one
>   of the push servers is down, the load balancing mechanism will
>   transparently direct your new connection to another server assuming
>   you connect by hostname and not by static IP address.

Is OS X Server (the "provider" in this context) essentially just "carrying on" by "re-establishing" the connection to APNS after being "idle" for several hours as noted in the logs per the stream error aformentioned?

Someone I spoke with about this posited the above problems may be due to the router's WAN port not being assigned a static IP address by my ISP, but of all the Apple developer documentation and support docs I've looked at about push notifications with OS X Server do not state a static IP address is required.

note: I have also tested this with the same hardware and settings but running OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion with Server app 2.2.1 with essentially the same results but IMHO better log verbosity, as in:

```
11/29/13 11:16:55.713 PM push_notify[11951]: stream: received error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer on: incoming stream: APN to host: gateway.push.apple.com:2195

11/29/13 11:16:55.722 PM push_notify[11951]: Disconnected from apn server gateway.push.apple.com for topic com.apple.mail.XServer.2a132c32-dda4-45a1-68e1-b3cca3865c12: error Connection reset by peer

11/29/13 11:16:55.722 PM push_notify[11951]: will attempt to reconnect stream APN to host gateway.push.apple.com:2195 in 15 seconds
```

Any help or suggestions resolving this would be greatly appreciated, it may be something simple I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We originally filed a bug report regarding this problem with Apple (at the time we weren't deterministically certain it was a bug, but considering the efforts we made to resolve this with Apple Enterprise support, it seemed probabilistically to be a bug). Recently Apple engineering responded to us stating they have attempted to fix this bug in Server app version 4. Server 4 requires to be run on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. We have tested with Server 4.0.3 running on OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite with two iPhones each running iOS 8.1.3 and our router remains a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter (with no changes to the router configuration). For earlier versions of Server, assuming this bug remains unfixed in those versions, the workaround offered by Josh may be your best best.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was been resolved. The ASUS "Dark Knight" router which was providing the private LAN  (NAT) and port forwarding to the Mac running OS X Server has a firmware bug. The bug manifest by DROPPING the ESTABLISHED TCP connection on port 2195 between the Mac running OS X Server and APNS, after two hours of quiescence. The router should not have dropped this connection, there was no firewall rule instructing it to do so. The lesson learned is to be much more selective and wise with regard to choosing routers (especially consumer off-the-shelf variety) for use with servers even for servers run in a small business context (like a Mac Mini Server).

## Heading

Comment: Great solution, how did you determine it was the router dropping the connection? (In my case the router is also the Internet gateway, so I can't simply remove it from the equation).

Comment: Apple Enterprise was very helpful in assisting me with debugging this situation. It took a while to figure this out because neither of us expected the router to drop packets. To finally isolate the problem, Apple Enterprise support asked me for a packet trace between the router and my ISP's modem. I connected a hub (not a switch) between the router and modem, and connected another computer to the hub. On this other computer I ran:

`sudo tcpdump -s 65535 -w ~/router_modem.wireshark port 2195 or port 2196 or port 5223 or port 1640`

This allowed us to finally diagnose it was the router (Asus).

Comment: We no longer have the Asus router to re-test it, sorry. It appears exceedingly likely this was, all along, a bug (see my update posted today about the bug fix from Apple in Server version 4 running on OS X 10.10 Yosemite)!

Answer (score 0):

My first steps in diagnosis would be to forward both those ports and see what happens (I might even put the machine into a DMZ for a couple of hours).

I'd then put a packet sniffer on the 17.0.0.0/8 address block and see what traffic on what ports is going across the net when it does work and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @user3051849 has the root cause, but in my case I can't swap out the router. So, enclosed are my two workarounds. As of OSX Server 3.1.2 this problem remains.

Use Apple's launchctl to create a job that runs every 2 hours to restart the mail server. So, this should only be used on mail servers that are not busy. Create a plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/MailRestart.plist, the contents should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mailrestart</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/etc/periodic/daily/500.restart-mail</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>7200</integer> <!-- Every 2 hours -->
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/daily.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that this launch agent runs Apple's `/etc/periodic/daily/500.restart-mail` script every 2 hours (7200 seconds). In case Apple removes the restart mail script, here is a [copy](https://gist.github.com/josh-h/e869c0957b2f44367cac) for your convenience.

As an aside, it seems Apple is aware of connection problems with their push service, as they created the periodic script to restart the mail server during the daily run of the `periodic` service. However, their fix is rather weak, because in my case the periodic service runs daily, but my connection to the push service is dropped after 2 hours of inactivity. So, I need something more frequent than a daily mail server restart.

Next from a shell invoke:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/MailRestart.plist
```

This command loads the script into the Launch Control service causing the script to run every 2 hours, logging to /var/log/daily.out (the same destination that the periodic service logs too). In my case I needed to change this to under an hour, rather than every 2.

**A Better Approach**
An alternative solution is to leave the mail daemon alone and kill the process that handles push notifications, ie. push_notify. This has the added benefit of not killing the mail daemons which may interrupt imap connections. For example, the command:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.push_notify
```

Stops the push_notify service, launchd immediately restarts the service afterwards. So, the new process will have a fresh connection to Apple's notification servers. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to wrap the above into a script and invoke it from a modified plist as above.

Comment: Thanks for contributing a workaround for those who are unable to swap out their router. In your workaround you wrote _It seems Apple is aware of the problem, but their fix is rather weak, as the periodic service runs daily._ Are you referring to a different problem other than what I originally posted about (push notification service dropping)? I replaced the Asus with Ubiquiti EdgeRouter but haven't yet re-instated OS X Server's Mail service (first I wanted to run the EdgeRouter with just the basic to confirm its configuration is stable). I can now re-test Mail service on OS X Server 3.1.2.

Comment: Apple's mail restart script is commented with _Restart mail, otherwise our push notifications get hung up._ Which seems to acknowledge the problem that push_notify can fail (either through our dumb routers dropping connections, or some other root cause. However, as I describe in my edited answer their script falls short. If you run into this problem again I recommend using launchctl to restart push_notify, which seems to be working for me.

Comment: Using a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter, which is an enterprise class router, not a "dumb" router, I can confirm that this same problem with Mail and push notifications persists just as it had with my previous Asus "dumb" router. This is disappointing, a workaround should **not** be required. Apple should fix this, especially with OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Server 4.0 waiting in the wings (blaming this problem on routers is mostly a red herring). I will next approach a workaround per your (Josh's) suggestion, thanks for helping identify a workaround solution.

Comment: Josh, I can't locate Apple's `/etc/periodic/daily/500.restart-mail` script on my instances of OS X Server, running OS X 10.9.4 and Server version 3.1.2. I checked my archived snapshots of OS X 10.8.4, 10.8.5 and previous Server versions. I checked `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/etc`. No luck. What version of OS X / Server are you using? I would like to see a copy of `500.restart-mail`, can you post it please? btw on OS X 10.9.4 / Server 3.1.2 the path to push_notify launchd is `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.push_notify.plist`

Comment: @user3051849 See the revised answer with a link to the script.  The Apple script does occasionally soft fail for me, as the Mail server doesn't always stop/start in time. Instead I've been restarting the push notify service which has been working well. I agree that this is a bug in Apple's push/notify not to recover gracefully from disconnects, any idea how to open a bug report with Apple? According to https://www.apple.com/support/osxserver/contact/ I'm past their support time period.